# Calculating the frequency of an if statements in a loop and the total Big Oh

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I have an example that I found online, and I wanted to check its frequency and the total Big Oh. However, I'm having trouble calculating the frequency of an if-else statement inside a loop, and I can't seem to find the answer online.

This is what I have so far:

```
1 int i, j, sum = 0;               // Frequency of 1
2 for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {        // Frequency of n + 1
3     if (i != 0)                  // Frequency of n
4         sum += i;                // Frequency of n-1
5     else for (j = 0; j < n; j++) // Frequency of n + 1
6         sum += j;                // Frequency of n
7 }                                // O(n)
```

I know when calculating the Big Oh, I should be looking at the worst case, but isn't at worst the else will run 1 time only? if so is my reasoning and solution correct? or should I assume that for example at line 5 will run (n (n + 1)) times? which will turn this into O(n^2)

This has been bugging me for days, and I've searched everywhere for the correct way to go about this, and I give up trying to figure it out.

Comment: *"I've searched everywhere for the correct way to go about this"* --- clearly you haven't. There are *literally millions* of big-O homework problems similar to this one on SO alone, let alone the entire internet.

Answer (score 0):

I think the overall complexity is O(n), based on the asymptotic behaviour for large n.
The loop over i clearly has n iterations. Within that loop, the loop over j is only executed once (when i==0), and the other (n-1) loops involve operations that are only O(1). So the overall complexity is the sum of two O(n) operations.

Comment: Yeh, I think this is it, thanks. I just needed to hear another opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying the following: Create a counter variable counter, and initialize counter to 0. Then, for each statement you execute, increment the counter by 1. So for example, try the following code:

```
int i, j, sum, counter = 0;
counter++; // incremented because initialization performed. Cost is O(1)
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  counter++; // incremented because for-loop condition checked.
  if (i != 0) {
    counter++; // incremented because if-condition checked
    sum += i;
    counter++; // incremented because sum incremented
  } else {
    counter++; // incremented because if-condition checked. reached other branch.
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      counter++; // incremented because for-loop condition met.
      sum += j;
      counter++; // incremented because sum incremented.
    }
    counter++; // incremented because for-loop condition failed.
  }
}
counter++; // incremented because for-loop condition failed.
println(counter); // Depending on language, find a way to do print.
```

Using this approach, you can verify your intuition when you supply different values for n. You will indeed find that the value for counter increases linearly, but this will formalize your intuition.